# Scala: Why is this pattern match code throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: exception, scala, pattern-matching

I was checking out a tutorial, found at 
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-4

This tutorial is from jan. 2008, I see, but I'm using Scala 2.8.0 if that makes a difference.

```
class Color(val red:Int, val green:Int, val blue:Int)

case class Red(r:Int) extends Color(r, 0, 0)
case class Green(g:Int) extends Color(0, g, 0)
case class Blue(b:Int) extends Color(0, 0, b)

def printColor(c:Color) = c match {
  case Red(v) => println("Red: " + v)
  case Green(v) => println("Green: " + v)
  case Blue(v) => println("Blue: " + v)

  case col:Color => {
    print("R: " + col.red + ", ")
    print("G: " + col.green + ", ")
    println("B: " + col.blue)
  }

  case null => println("Invalid color")
}
```

When entering this into the interpreter, it produces

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:53)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:45)

plus another 185 lines of tracing, and the interpreter exits.

What does this error message mean, and can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: So it does! A little cut and pasting shows the problem is the "case null"  - but just using the class Color line and only the case null in the match doesn't error. I've no idea why, other than a compiler bug. 2.8.1 is out, might be worth trying with that?

Comment: And (for me) it works when fed to scala as a file, it's only the interactive line by line that blows up

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation about working as a compiled file. I guess it's not the syntax, then?  I've had some other odd issues with the interpreter before. I thought it might be that line, too - I tried changing it to `case _ => println("Invalid color")`, which was all I could really think of, but that doesn't help. Perhaps I'll try 2.8.1 and see if maybe this was a bug that has been fixed, or something.

Comment: Minimal example: `class A(val a: Int); case class AA(aa: Int) extends A(aa); AA(1) match { case AA(a) => a }`. If you replace the semicolons with newlines, it fails in REPL. With semicolons or with parentheses around, it runs without problems.

Comment: @Debilski thanks, I see what you mean.  Indeed, when I put this all one one lines with semicolons and paste it into the interpreter it works fine. Why not post that as an answer, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A message like that is always a bug.  Specifically https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4025 .

Comment: Yeah, the way it exited the REPL itself seemed like something was wrong beyond just syntax. Thanks for clearing this up.